# What is so special about Higman's Lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, order-theory

Is there a motivational example of an application of Higman's Lemma that brings out the true beauty and importance of Higman's Lemma? What is the thing that made so many people care about it? For an example, I was thinking that given a singleton set $\{1\}$ with the linear order $\preceq$ such that basically $1\preceq1$. Now take the free monoid of this singleton and you get an infinite set $\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ which is the positive natural numbers $\mathbb{N}_+$. If we define the same linear order $\preceq$ on the free monoid $\mathbb{N}_+$, we get $1\preceq2\preceq\cdots$. And therefore the order on the singleton set $\{1\}$ satisfies the free monoid $\mathbb{N}_+$ as well. I am not sure how important this example is but I remember that this is how I came to understand the lemma. I also thought of the huge range of flexibility to this lemma but could not come up with anything to fully encompass the true beauty behind this wonderful lemma. Like finding a generalization/construction in category theory, which is what I am currently working on, and thus opening new doors for discovery.

Comment: you should read http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~schwicht/papers/jaeger14/higman.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-quasi-ordering, the lemma looks to be about the proof by induction : is it allowed to prove something by induction on a set $S$ using a well-quasiorder $\le$ on $S$ ? that is if  "$P(x)$ is true and $x \le y$ implies $P(y)$ is true", is it enough to prove $P(x)$ for finitely many $x \in S$ to prove $P(x)$ is true for every $x \in S$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I already read those a long time ago and found nothing. In fact I have pretty much read most if not all Higman's-Lemma-related papers. So I need more.

Comment: @JulianRachman If you are looking for *more* references you haven't seen, you're going to have to list what you have already read. At least, if you *don't* want to force everyone to play a rude guessing game that makes everyone hate you. Good luck

Comment: [this link](http://www.dagstuhl.de/de/programm/kalender/semhp/?semnr=16031) has compelling stuff about quasi orders, which should in turn support Higman's lemma

Comment: @rschwieb Ok. Well I am not asking for _more_ references. I want to see motivational example(s) that bring out the beauty and importance of Higman's Lemma. It is all stated in my question with no mentioning of wanting "references."

Comment: This seems to say that if infinitely many monkeys start typing then (they will not necessarily reproduce a Shakespearian sonnet but) one of the monkeys will type a substring of another monkey's magnum opus.  Is this correct?

Comment: @user72694 Unique analogy; but yes.

Comment: I suppose just like with the induction axiom you don't begin to appreciate the significance of this technical result until you see applications, so waxing eloquent about true beauty etc will probably will only be effective if accompanied by applications. What do you think?

Comment: @user72694 I see what you mean. So do you have any applications in mine or one application that truly stands out that I can use to represent the beauty and importance of this lemma?

Comment: I just learned about Higman's lemma five minutes ago. You want me to give applications already? I appreciate it though :-)

Comment: @user72694 My apologies. Take your time. I did not mean to rush you or anything like that. :)

Comment: Also I would edit your comment on your page to the effect that *Also, check out my blog as I try to display my knowledge*.

Comment: @user72694 Well noted. Let me know when you have something. :)

Comment: @user72694 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35635/discussion-between-julian-rachman-and-user72694) when you are ready. Or unless you want to answer the question.

Comment: You might want to award a 50pt bounty for this to get people to contribute additional applications.

Comment: @user72694 ok. I will do so.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure this is the answer you expect, but here is an important application of Higman's lemma in formal language theory. Let $A$ be a finite alphabet and let 
$A^*$ be the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on $A$. The *shuffle product* of two [languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) $U$ and $V$ over $A$ is the language
\begin{multline*}
 U \operatorname{ш} V = \{ w \in A^* \mid w = \color{red}{u_1}\color{blue}{v_1} \cdots \color{red}{u_n}\color{blue}{v_n} \text{ for
 some words $\color{red}{u_1, \ldots, u_n}$} \\
 \text{$\color{blue}{v_1, \ldots, v_n}$ of $A^*$ such that $\color{red}{u_1 \cdots u_n} \in
 U$ and $\color{blue}{v_1 \cdots v_n} \in V$} \}\,.
\end{multline*}
Note that in this definition, $\color{red}{u_1, \ldots, u_n}$ as well as $\color{blue}{v_1, \dots, v_n}$ can be empty words.
The following result is a consequence of Higman's lemma.

**Theorem**. For each language $L$, the language $L \operatorname{ш} A^*$ is a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

This gives examples of languages that are known to be regular, but for which there is no known finite automaton (or regular expression) representing them, a rather disturbing situation.

This result does not use the full strength of Higman's lemma, only the fact that the subword order on $A^*$ is a well-quasi-order.

**Definition**. A word $u = \color{red}{a_1a_2 \dotsm a_n}$ (where $a_1, a_2, \dots a_n \in A$) is a *subword* of a word $v$ if there exist $v_0, v_1, \dots, v_n \in A^*$ such that $v = v_0\color{red}{a_1}v_1\color{red}{a_2}v_2 \dotsm v_{n-1}\color{red}{a_n}v_n$.

By Higman's lemma, the subword order on $A^*$ is a well-quasi-order. Therefore, for each language $L$, the set $F$ of minimal words  of $L$ (for the subword ordering) is a finite set $F$ and $L \operatorname{ш} A^* = F \operatorname{ш} A^*$. It is now easy to show that $F \operatorname{ш} A^*$ is a regular language.

Comment: This is great. But you refer to this not bringing the "full strength" of the lemma. What do you think will bring out its "full strength"?

Comment: I was thinking of an alphabet which is itself well-quasi ordered.

Comment: Go on. I think you are on to something. See I thought that the fact that Higman's Lemma is so usable in many areas of computation that if we bring out that aspect, it would be a good example. However I still think you are on to something.

Answer (score 1):

In a vein similar to Pin's answer.

The set of all strings that include some string as a subword (or subsequence) is a called a (principal) Shuffle Ideal (SI).  The class of stringsets that are Boolean combinations of a finite set of SIs is called the Piecewise Testable stringsets.  If one restricts to intersections of the complements of SIs one gets the Strictly Piecewise stringsets.

Via a sequence of lemmas, all of them easy except Higman's lemma,  this turns out to be exactly the class of stringsets that are closed under subsequence.

See:

@InCollection{,
author = {James Rogers and Jeffrey Heinz and Gil Bailey and Matt Edlefsen and Molly Visscher and David Wellcome and Sean Wibel},
    title = {On languages piecewise testable in the strict sense},
    booktitle = {The Mathematics of Language: Revised Selected Papers from the 10th and 11th Biennial  Conference  on  the  Mathematics  of Language},
  publisher = {FoLLI/Springer},
  year =      2010,
  editor =    {Christian  Ebert and  Gerhard  J{\"a}ger  and Jens Michaelis},
  volume =    6149,
  series =    {LNCS/LNAI},
  pages =     {255-265}}

Jim Rogers